# how do i load 5 rows in UItableview and after scroll down again i will load 5 more rows in swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Below is the my code!!!

```
import UIKit

  class myhomefeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate  {
    var tableData = []
    var imageCache = [String:UIImage]()
    var imageCache1 = [String:UIImage]()
    var imageCache2 = [String:UIImage]()
    @IBOutlet var appsTableView: UITableView!
     var refreshControl:UIRefreshControl!

    let PageSize = 5


@IBOutlet var tableViewFooter:Reload!
var loading = false

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tableViewFooter.hidden = true
    loadmyhomefeeddata(0, size: PageSize)

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refreshControl.addTarget(self, action: "refresh:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    self.appsTableView.addSubview(refreshControl)

}

func refresh(refreshControl: UIRefreshControl) {

     loadmyhomefeeddata(0, size: PageSize)
    refreshControl.endRefreshing()
}

func loadSegment(offset:Int, size:Int) {

    if (!self.loading) {

        self.setLoadingState(true)

        if currentpage < toPage {      

        }
        else if currentpage > toPage
        {
           self.setLoadingState(false)
        } 
    }
else
    {
      println("Not Loading")

    }
}    

func setLoadingState(loading:Bool) {
    self.loading = loading
    self.tableViewFooter.hidden = !loading
}    

 func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let currentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    let maximumOffset = scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height

    if (maximumOffset - currentOffset) <= 40 {
        loadSegment(currentpage, size: tableData.count)
    }
}

// pull to refresh list        

@IBAction func writeyouridea(sender: AnyObject) {

    let viewController=self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("writeyouridea") as? UIViewController
    self.presentViewController(viewController!, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

// MARK: - Table view data source
 func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    // #warning Potentially incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete method implementation.
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return tableData.count;

}

 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myhomefeedcell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! myhomefeedTableViewCell

    // Configure the cell...
    if let rowData: NSDictionary = self.tableData[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary,
        urlString = rowData["imgfile"] as? String,
        imgURL = NSURL(string: urlString),
     //   imgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: imgURL),

        countryString = rowData["cflag"] as? String,
        countryimgURL = NSURL(string: countryString),
     //   countryimgData = NSData(contentsOfURL: countryimgURL),

        ideaimageString = rowData["ideapicture"] as? String,
        ideaimageURL = NSURL(string: ideaimageString),
     //   ideaimagedata = NSData(contentsOfURL: ideaimageURL),

        userfullname = rowData["name"] as? String,

        category = rowData["categoryname"] as? String,
        ideadesc = rowData["idea"] as? String,
        time = rowData["createddate"] as? String,
        ideatitle = rowData["title"] as? String {

            cell.ideadesc.text = ideadesc
            cell.username.text = userfullname
            cell.categoryname.text = category
            cell.feedimage.image = UIImage(named: "cross")
            cell.userimage.image = UIImage(named: "cross")
            cell.country.image = UIImage(named: "cross")
            cell.title.text = ideatitle
            cell.time.text = time

            //country
            if let countryimg = imageCache1[countryString] {
                cell.country.image = countryimg
            }
            else {

                let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: countryimgURL)
                let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        let imagecountry = UIImage(data: data)
                        self.imageCache1[countryString] = imagecountry
                        // Update the cell
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            cell.country.image = imagecountry
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
            }

            //userimage
            if let userimg = imageCache2[urlString] {
                cell.userimage.image = userimg
            }
            else {

                let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: imgURL)
                let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
                NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {
                        let imageuser = UIImage(data: data)
                        self.imageCache2[urlString] = imageuser
                        // Update the cell
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                            cell.userimage.image = imageuser
                        })
                    }
                    else {
                        println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                    }
                })
            }      

            if cell.feedimage.image != nil
            {

                if let img = imageCache[ideaimageString] {
                    cell.feedimage.image = img
                }
                else {

                    let request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: ideaimageURL)
                    let mainQueue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()
                    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: mainQueue, completionHandler: { (response, data, error) -> Void in
                        if error == nil {
                            let image = UIImage(data: data)
                            self.imageCache[ideaimageString] = image
                            // Update the cell
                            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                                cell.feedimage.image = image
                            })
                        }
                        else {
                            println("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                        }
                    })
                }
            }

    }

    return cell
}

func loadmyhomefeeddata(offset:Int, size:Int) {

    let rowslimit = size
    let urlPath = "url address?noofrowslimit=\(rowslimit)"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url!, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        if(error != nil) {
            // If there is an error in the web request, print it to the console
            println(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        var err: NSError?
        if let jsonResult = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: &err) as? NSDictionary {
            if(err != nil) {
                // If there is an error parsing JSON, print it to the console
                println("JSON Error \(err!.localizedDescription)")
            }
            //  println(jsonResult)

            if let results: NSArray = jsonResult["results"] as? NSArray {
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                    self.tableData = results
                    self.appsTableView!.reloadData()
                })
            }
        }
    })


    task.resume()

}   

}
```

Comment: There is a lot of code here and the question is not very clear!  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to have a infinite scroll? If so, you could try the following. First of all, make the `task` an instance variable of your controller then add the following `UIScrollViewDelegate`.

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
  // If you are already loading elements, return. This method is called multiple times
  if task?.state == .Running { // You could use the isLoading variable instead
    return
  }

  let offSetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
  let triggerY = scrollView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height
  if (offSetY >= triggerY) {
    // The offset of elements should be the amount you currently have, and you want to fetch 5 more elements
    self.loadmyhomefeeddata(tableData.count, size: 5)
  }
}
```

Comment: how can i make task an instance variable?

Comment: Add a property to your controller. ``var task: NSURLSessionDataTask?``. And remove the ``let`` keyword from your ``loadmyhomefeeddata`` function in this line `` let task = session.dataTaskWithURL..``